MicroPhyton Wifi assistance with Pico Pi W
I am super new to programming with MicroPyton. I watched a couple viddeos on circuit python as I wanted to get my Pico Pi W connected via bluetooth to be able to contorl the LEDs I attached to it. Come to find out that Circuit Python does not support bluetooth even though the Pico Pi W supports it. I was told that I would need to most likely use CircuitPython as its similar but should get the job done. I was looking and I couldnt find any code or something that would allow me to connect via bluetooth, but I did find a wifi connect code. My code lets me connect to a wifi network (as long as I know the SSID and password) I can then connect to if by surfing to the IP address the Pico picks up. It will project a very basic html page with buttons on it that will allow me to statically change the the color. I can change it from red to blue to green and then off. When i try to make it run an animation of sorts (needs to be in a loop to do so, at least my very little knowledge tells me I need to do so.) it seems to disconnect from the wifi connection(at least stop broadcasting itself) and not allow me to change colors back to a static color or even off. I have to either disconnect the power to the board/manually stop the program from running in Thonny. I will paste my code below to see if anyone can help.
import network
import socket
import machine, neopixel, random, math, time
from time import sleep
from picozero import pico_led

p = machine.Pin.board.GP0
n = neopixel.NeoPixel(p, 30)

ssid = ''
password = ''

def connect():
    #Connect to the WLAN
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wlan.active(True)
    wlan.connect(ssid, password)
    while wlan.isconnected() == False:
        print('Waiting for connection...')
        sleep(1)
    ip = wlan.ifconfig()[0]
    print(f'Connected on {ip}')
    return ip


def open_socket(ip):
    #Open a socket
    address = (ip, 80)
    connection = socket.socket()
    connection.bind(address)
    connection.listen(1)
    return connection


def webpage(state):
    #Template HTML
    html = f"""
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <body>
            <form action="./red">
            <input type="submit" value="RED" />
            </form>
            <form action="./green">
            <input type="submit" value="GREEN" />
            </form>
            <form action="./blue">
            <input type="submit" value="BLUE" />
            </form>
            <form action="./xmas">
            <input type="submit" value="xmas" />
            </form>
            <form action="./lightoff">
            <input type="submit" value="light off" />
            </form>
            <p>LED is {state}</p>
            </body>
            </html>
            """
    return str(html)

## Create a random function
def randint(lower, upper):
    gap = upper - lower
    if gap == 0:
        return lower
    return (random.getrandbits(int(math.log(gap, 2)))% gap) + lower

ChristmasColors = [(255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0)]
AllColors = [(255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 255)]
WhiteBlue = [(255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 255), (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 255)]
Red = [(255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0)]
Blue = [(0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 255)]
Green = [(0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 0)]
Yellow = [(255, 255, 0), (255, 255, 0), (255, 255, 0), (255, 255, 0)]
Orange = [(255, 165, 0),(255, 165, 0), (255, 165, 0), (255, 165, 0)]
Fire = [(255, 165, 0), (255, 0, 0), (255, 165, 0), (255, 0, 0)]

def serve(connection):
    #Start a web server
    state = 'OFF'
    pico_led.off()
    while True:
        client = connection.accept()[0]
        request = client.recv(1024)
        request = str(request)
        print(request)
        try:
            request = request.split()[1]
        except IndexError:
            pass
        if request == '/red?':
            pico_led.on()
            for i in range(30):
                n[i] = (i * 8, 0, 0)
                n.write()
            state = 'RED'
        elif request == '/green?':
            pico_led.on()
            for i in range(30):
                n[i] = (0, i * 8, 0)
                n.write()
            state = 'GREEN'
        elif request == '/blue?':
            pico_led.on()
            for i in range(30):
                n[i] = (0, 0, i * 8)
                n.write()
            state = 'BLUE'
        elif request == '/xmas?':
            pico_led.on()
            try:
                while True:
                    for i in range(30):
                        n[i] = ChristmasColors[randint(0,4)]
                        #n[i-2] = (0,0,0)
                        n.write()
                        machine.idle()
                        time.sleep(.01)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                pico_led.off()
                state = 'YELLOW'
        elif request == '/lightoff?':
            pico_led.off()
            for i in range(30):
                n[i] = (0, 0, 0)
                n.write()
            state = 'OFF'
        html = webpage(state)
        client.send(html)
        client.close()
        
            
try:
    ip = connect()
    connection = open_socket(ip)
    serve(connection)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    machine.reset()

I do want to try and get this swapped over to bluetooth and use a bluetooth compatible app on my cell phone (iPhone 15) to connect instead of wifi as I would have to run a hot spot to get it to connect while out and a bout with my prop. Can anyone lend some assistance on this please and thank you in advance!
Regards,
Andrew
I have tried to eliminate the loop but if I do then it becuase just a static xmas color (alternating red green) when its supposed to swap randomly between the two colors looking like xmas lights. I have tried adding break statements but they dont seem to work. I am not sure what exaclty I am doing wrong.

When does your while True loop end?

Which one? There seems to be two loops. There is the MAIN one that runs all the settings and lets me change the colors by pressing the other buttons and that will run and continue to let me change colors as long as I need to,  but when I intiate the xmas button/loop thats where it "breaks". I would like to be able to select the xmas button/loop and have it run until I press another button or power it off. I dont know if its possible which is why I am seeing if the smarter people out here can help with it.

The problem is that your "xmas loop" never terminates. While your pico is happily blinking LEDs, it does not check for new commands nor communicate in any other way. You would have to handle your blinking in a background thread or restructure your code as in (e.g.) this guide.

I think that is part of what I am trying to have it do. I want it to run that loop until i press another button which would exit that look and take us back to the main one, but that loop needs to not break connectivity to the main loop. Hopefully that something that is doable.
